# I am unable to make my first GUI work

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionevent

I have been working on a basic GUI application in my Java class for our teacher before he had started formally teaching the subject and introducing the proper objects and syntax for setting up a GUI, leaving me on my own to scavenge for answers.  The application itself is called `StringApps` but is incomplete, as when I was testing one of the textfield responses it was not giving me a message dialog that I had requested in the code.  Here is the following code and the Utility class to go with it:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

public class StringApps extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel lblIntro;
    private JButton btnReverseString;
    private JButton btnVowelCounter;
    private JButton btnPalindromeTester;
    private JLabel lblReverseString;
    private JLabel lblVowelCounter;
    private JLabel lblPalindromeTester;
    private JTextField txtFldReverseString;
    private JTextField txtFldVowelCounter;
    private JTextField txtFldPalindromeTester;
    private JButton btnConfirm1;
    private JButton btnConfirm2;
    private JButton btnConfirm3;
    private ButtonListener listener;

    public StringApps()
    {
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setTitle("String Apps");
        lblIntro = new JLabel("Welcome to String Apps");
        btnReverseString = new JButton("String Reverser");
        btnVowelCounter = new JButton("Vowel Counter");
        btnPalindromeTester = new JButton("Palindrome Tester");
        btnReverseString.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        btnVowelCounter.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        btnPalindromeTester.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        cp.add(lblIntro);
        cp.add(btnReverseString);
        cp.add(btnVowelCounter);
        cp.add(btnPalindromeTester);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600, 400);
    }//StringApps

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
      StringApps foo = new StringApps();
    }//main

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Container cp = getContentPane();
            Object clicked = e.getSource();
            lblReverseString = new JLabel("Please enter your String here:");
            txtFldReverseString = new JTextField(15);
            btnConfirm1 = new JButton("Okay");
            lblVowelCounter = new JLabel("Please enter your String here:");
            txtFldVowelCounter = new JTextField(15);
            btnConfirm2 = new JButton("Okay");
            lblPalindromeTester = new JLabel("Please enter your String here:");
            txtFldPalindromeTester = new JTextField(15);
            btnConfirm3 = new JButton("Okay");

            if(clicked == btnReverseString)
            {
                cp.add(lblReverseString);
                cp.add(txtFldReverseString);
                cp.add(btnConfirm1);
                if(clicked == btnConfirm1)
                {
                    String fwd = txtFldReverseString.getText();
                    txtFldReverseString.selectAll();
                    String rev = StringUtil.reverseString(fwd);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ("String Reversed: " + rev));
                }
            }//if
            else if(clicked == btnVowelCounter)
            {

            }
            else if(clicked == btnPalindromeTester)
            {
            }
        }//actionPerformed
    }//ButtonListener
}//StringApps(class)
```

Utility Class:

```
public class StringUtil
{
    public static String reverseString(String fwd)
    {
        String rev = "";
        for(int i = fwd.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            rev += fwd.charAt(i);
        return rev;
    }
    public static int vowelCounter(String word)
    {
        int vowels = 0;
        word.toLowerCase();
        for(int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if(word.charAt(i) == 'a'|| word.charAt(i) == 'e'|| word.charAt(i) == 'i'||word.charAt(i) == 'o'||word.charAt(i) == 'u')
                vowels++;
        }
        return vowels;
    }
    public static boolean palindromeTest(String word)
    {
        boolean palindrome;
        String rev, fwd, strip = "";
        word.toLowerCase();
        for(int i = 0; i <= word.length() - 1; i++)
            if((word.charAt(i) > 47 && word.charAt(i) < 58)||(word.charAt(i) > 96 && word.charAt(i) < 123))
                strip += word.charAt(i);
        fwd = strip;
        rev = reverseString(fwd);
        if(rev.equals(fwd))
            palindrome = true;
        else
            palindrome = false;
        return palindrome;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at windows-builder for eclipse. Then compare the code it generates versus what you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you miss understand how GUI's work.  Unlike console applications, they don't run in a linear fashion, they are generally event driven.

The clicks or types something, a series of events are raised and you respond to them.

In you `ButtonListener`, you respond to the `btnReverseString` event by updating the UI and checking to see if the `clicked` source is equal to the button you just created and added...this isn't going to work for two reasons.

The first is, each time `actionPerformed` you create a new instance of `btnConfirm1`, meaning that `clicked` and `btnConfirm1` could never be equal and two, the user has can't have clicked both `btnReverseString` AND `btnConfirm1`.

Start by taking a look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [How to make dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html), which will allow you to ask questions of the user inline to your running code (which is what it seems you are trying to do ;))

Comment: Sorry I have not rated your answer yet, as I was still testing it to see it as a plausible solution.  I went to the first link you sent me, but after trying NetBeans, which the tutorial is based on, I decided that attempting to fix my own code was the best option.  I eventually came up with a solution to make the entire program work but it still needs a lot of adjustments.  Thank you for you answer and seeing as no one else replied for hours after you, I'll just grant you as the answerer.